# Displaying List<string> in a grid column

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-gridcontrol

Is there a way that one can use a control in a gridview that displays a simple `List<string>` in a dropdown just like `SearchLookUp` or even a simple Dropdown? The tricky part is that this `List<string>` is not predefined, it can change **for each row** in the grid.

For example if I have a grid with each row representing an `ECU` of a vehicle. This object contains a `List<string>` representing `SoftwareVersion` allowed for the `ECU`, among st which the user can then select one that is in accordance to their needs. Since each `ECU` can have different software versions, I cannot assign a pre-defined data source and bind it to `SearchLookUpEdit` . So I am searching for a solution to make it happen.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a RepositoryItemComboBox control for this. In order to have a different list of ECU items in each row, handle the GridView's [CustomRowCellEdit](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.CustomRowCellEdit.event) event and assign the editor at runtime.

You can add all of the strings in your List to the editor's [Items](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemComboBox.Items.property) collection and additionally set the [TextEditStyle property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemButtonEdit.TextEditStyle.property) to TextEditStyles.DisableTextEditor to prevent the end-user from typing in their own values.